# Where to find the SQLite table created in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am doing first steps in SQLite, following this tutorial: //https://www.developersoapbox.com/connecting-to-a-sqlite-database-using-net-core/ that create a table in C#, but I cant find it to open it in DB Browser.
If I understand it correctly it has to do with the  SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder whith which I am setting the datasource like this:

```
csBuilder.DataSource = "./myDb.db";
```

Sorry if it makes no sense

Comment: So `.` is the current directory for the process, so most likely it (attempted) to create the file in the same place as the .exe program file.

Comment: perfect! Thanks a lot !